# Ajax query to Service method with multiple parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, service

I need to make an Ajax query to call a method in a Service object that takes 3 parameters and returns a boolean. I then use this Boolean for a validation message that happens pre-post.

This is what I have at the moment (not working) but I've tried other things but to no avail. We're using JQuery and Grails:

```
var isUnique = ${remoteFunction(
    service: 'Project', 
    action:'checkUniqueUserProjectId',
    params:{
        // These values are from  hidden fields in the form.
        // userId and projectId are string values and the group is an object
        uniqueId: userId,
        group: userGroup,
        projectId: myProjectId
    }
)}
```

Here's the method that is called in the ProjectService:

```
// Check whether or not a Project with the provided uniqueId already exists 
// in the database that is not itself.
def checkUniqueUserProjectId(uniqueId,group,projectId) {
    def filterCriteria = Project.createCriteria()
    def projectList = filterCriteria.list {
        and {
            eq("userProjectId", uniqueId)
            eq("group", group)
            ne("id",projectId)
        }
    }

    if(projectList.empty)
        return true
    else
        return false
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a remote function with the code as follows:

```
${remoteFunction(action: 'isUniqueId', params: '\'uniqueid=\'+userId+\'&project_id=\'+myProjectId', onFailure:'$("#project").submit()', onSuccess:'verifyUniqueness(data, textStatus,detailsMessage)') }
```

....

```
function verifyUniqueness(data, textStatus,detailsMessage) {
    if (data == 'false') {
        detailsMessage = detailsMessage + "A Project with the provided Project ID already exists.";
    }

    if (detailsMessage.trim() != '' ) { 
        stackedSummary.section('details', '<font style="color:red; font-weight:normal; line-height:0px;">' + detailsMessage + '</font>');
    } else {
        $('#project').submit();
    }
}
```

ProjectController

```
def isUniqueId = {
    def project = Project.get(params.project_id)
    if (project == null) {
        render(projectService.checkUniqueUserProjectId(params.uniqueid, null, null)) as JSON
    } else {
        render(projectService.checkUniqueUserProjectId(params.uniqueid, project.group, project.id)) as JSON
    }
}
```

Thank you everyone for your help! You helped lead me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('Project/checkUniqueUserProjectId', {
        uniqueId : userId,
        group    : userGroup,
        projectId: myProjectId
}, 
function (response) {
    if (response.firstChild.textContent=="true") {
        alert("hola mundo");
    }
});
```

Is better if response is format JSON

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, jdnichollsc :)

Unfortunately, I'm getting an Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation error on the $.post. Should this be post? I'm trying to render a message to the user if the checkUniqueUserProjectId returns a true without refreshing the page.

Comment: I changed the parameters to an array and it seemed to get rid of the error I was getting but it still isn't displaying an alert in either the true or false case. I think I'm calling it wrong...

Comment: do console.log(response); and see

Answer (score 0):

So in your controller:

```
if ( projectService.checkUniqueUserProjectId(params.uniqueId, params.group, params.projectId) )
{
    render([:] as JSON)
}
else
{
    response.status = 403
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var isUnique;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "contextPath/controller/action",
    data: {uniqueId: userId, group: userGroup, projectId: myProjectId},
    success: function() { isUnique = true; },
    error: function() { isUnique = false; },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: The validation needs to occur pre-post. It's a message that shows in the UI, similar to if they forgot to input some data into a required field. These messages show before attempting a save to the database